# Can't open saved video using OpenCV in Python (Windows 10)

Tags: python, opencv, video-processing

Code reads the `train1.mov` file, shows `cv2.imshow('res', res)` also saves a file named `output.avi`. Problem is, output.avi is around 40 kb and empty. But `cv2.imshow('res', res)` shows the whole video. Then show the following error.

Python Code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('C:\\Users\\khan1\\Desktop\\python project\\color_threshold\\train1.mov')

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('C:\\Users\\khan1\\Desktop\\python project\\color_threshold\\output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))

while(cap.isOpened()):
    _, frame = cap.read()

    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    lower_green = np.array([40, 60, 60]) 
    upper_green = np.array([80, 255, 255])

    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_green, upper_green)
    mask = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask, (7, 7), 0)
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=mask)

    out.write(res)

    cv2.namedWindow("res", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.imshow('res', res)
    if (cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF) == ord('q'): # Hit `q` to exit
         break

# Release everything if job is finished
out.release()
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed ((scn == 3 || scn == 4) && (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_32F)) in cv::cvtColor, file C:\build\master_winpack-bindings-win32-vc14-static\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp, line 9815
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/khan1/Desktop/python project/color_threshold/savevid.py", line 19, in <module>
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
cv2.error: C:\build\master_winpack-bindings-win32-vc14-static\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:9815: error: (-215) (scn == 3 || scn == 4) && (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_32F) in function cv::cvtColor


Process finished with exit code 1
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Well the error happens before the video writer is closed, so that's why there's nothing written to the movie. It's possible that this is happening on the very last frame of the video. The `cap.read()` function returns (to your ignored variable `_`) `True` or `False` if there's no frame, and it could be trying to convert that empty frame. I.e. `cap.isOpened()` is `True` for the last frame but you need to exit the loop before it. So you need an `if retval: <processing> else: quit`. See the last example [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d43/tutorial_py_video_display.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's clear your error is happening on the last frame; that's why your `imshow` is still working the whole time but it errors out and doesn't complete writing the video which happens after the `while` loop.

The first value returned by `cap.read()` is a boolean on whether or not the frame exists/was read. So you can simply insert an `if-else` block in your code to perform your processing if the frame was read, and `quit` the `while` loop if not, so that you can finish writing the frame.

This should patch up your code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('C:\\Users\\khan1\\Desktop\\python project\\color_threshold\\train1.mov')

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('C:\\Users\\khan1\\Desktop\\python project\\color_threshold\\output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:

        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        lower_green = np.array([40, 60, 60]) 
        upper_green = np.array([80, 255, 255])

        mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_green, upper_green)
        mask = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask, (7, 7), 0)
        res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=mask)

        out.write(res)

        cv2.namedWindow("res", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
        cv2.imshow('res', res)
        if (cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF) == ord('q'): # Hit `q` to exit
            break
    else:
        break

# Release everything if job is finished
out.release()
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

See an example of this same process [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d43/tutorial_py_video_display.html).

Comment: That solved the error part. Thanks.Now there is no error message. But `output.avi` is still a 8 kb file which is empty. Why `out.write(res)` is not working?  @Alexander Reynolds

Comment: I'm not sure. On Windows there is an [optional flag for the `VideoWriter` constructor `isColor`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videowriter-videowriter) for whether it writes grayscale or color---not sure if that will help. Pass `isColor=False` into the `VideoWriter` constructor at the top. Also make sure that you actually have the `XVID` codec.  From [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/100967/codecs-list/): "on Windows, `VideoWriter` uses `MJPG` or `VFW API` thus ... any available codec that is `VFW` compliant can be used"